# Стоит ли определить connection и cursor как self переменные?

Tags: python, mysql

Python, mysql-connector-python.
Надоело постоянно таскать подключения mysql по небольшим внутренним функциям.
Можно ли сделать как то так?

```
...
def some_finc():
    q = "some query to mysql"
    self.cursor.execute(q)
    self.connection.commit()

with connect(...) as self.connection:
    with self.connection.cursor() as self.cursor:
        some_func()
```

Или же почему этого делать не следует, и стоит продолжать делать как то так?

```
def some_finc(conn, cur):
    q = "some query to mysql"
    cur.execute(q)
    conn.commit()

with connect(...) as connection:
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        some_func(connection, cursor)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Можно, но**

Это может вызвать проблемы с утечкой ресурсов, если соединение не будет корректно закрыто. Также, при необходимости многопоточного доступа, это может вызвать конфликты.

Относительно использования **self** для **connection** и **cursor**, это зависит от того, как вы планируете использовать их внутри класса. Если эти объекты будут часто использоваться в методах класса, то можно сделать так как вы предлагаете.

Comment: Хм. Ясненько. Надо будет обдумать. О! А это, хм. Если я присваиваю подключение `self`, в какой момент оно будет закрыто? Т.е. допустим, у меня `GUI`, я в `init` открываю подключение и пихаю его в `self`, у меня это подключение схлопнется как только отработает `init`, или будет существовать до конца существования `GUI`?

Comment: @Gh0sTG0 
Если вы присваиваете подключение в классе, это подключение будет существовать до тех пор, пока объект этого класса будет существовать. Следовательно, если вы используете это подключение внутри вашего GUI класса и инициализируете его в методе init, оно будет существовать до тех пор, пока объект вашего GUI класса будет активным и не будет уничтожен или удален.

Comment: А звучит любопытно, однако! Определенно любопытно. Спасибо за ответы.